# UnknownFormatConversionException: Android strings.xml format <![CDATA[ ...%1$... ]]>

Tags: android, formatting, android-xml, cdata

I'm trying to use formatted html inside *strings.xml*. So in *strings.xml* I have following:

```
<string name="application_start_message" formatted="false">
    <![CDATA[ bla bla bla %1$ bla bla bla %1$.... ]]>
<string name="application_website_url">website.com</string>
```

and later in code I do:

```
String string = getString(
    R.string.application_start_message,
    getString(R.string.application_website_url)
);
```

the runtime exception I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.artigile.checkmyphone/
    com.artigile.checkmyphone.MainActivity}: 
    java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: <
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: <
at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.unknownFormatConversionException(Formatter.java:1399)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.checkFlags(Formatter.java:1336)
at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1442)
at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1988)
at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:354)
at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:347)
at com.artigile.checkmyphone.MainActivity.buildModalStartWarningWindow(MainActivity.java:280)
at com.artigile.checkmyphone.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:116)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
... 11 more
```

Any thoughts how this can be workarounded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a typo in your question, but it doesn't look like you're closing the string tag and you're variable isn't correct.  The carriage return may also be problem, so get rid of that too.

Change:

```
<string name="application_start_message" formatted="false">
    <![CDATA[ bla bla bla %1$ bla bla bla %1$.... ]]>
```

To

```
<string name="application_start_message" formatted="false"><![CDATA[ bla bla bla %1$s bla bla bla %1$s .... ]]></string>
```

Comment: ha, man, seems like that was it... :( feel embarrassed not for asking such a stupid question:)

Comment: No worries at all. IMO there are no stupid questions, although others on SO seem to disagree w/ that sentiment. :-)